# AVPlayer crash on simulator

Tags: ios, crash, avplayer

I got this problem when I play a video using `AVPlayer` on Simulator since I updated my project to run in Xcode8. 
Here are the logs:

sometime like this:

```
    libBacktraceRecording.dylib`__gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook_block_invoke:
    0x10d165ea8 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10d165ea9 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x10d165eac <+4>:  movq   0x20(%rsi), %rax
    0x10d165eb0 <+8>:  movq   0x20(%rdi), %rcx
    0x10d165eb4 <+12>: cmpq   0x8(%rcx), %rax
    0x10d165eb8 <+16>: sete   %al
    0x10d165ebb <+19>: popq   %rbp
    0x10d165ebc <+20>: retq
```

Has anyone got this problem? Seems like a block rise it.